# How to set up reverse proxy with Angular CLI for specific js file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a script tag in the index.html page that I need to point to a local file that gets a reverse proxy to an external file.

jquery used here has a placeholder because it was the first thing I thought of that would be hosted on a cdn. I'm not actually mixing angular and jquery in my project :D.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="fake/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

ANGULAR CLI PROXY

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [{
    context: ["/fake/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"],
    target: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js",
    secure: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
}];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

but this throws a 404 at `localhost:4200/fake/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js`.

I do get a "the proxy tried" message in powershell though. `[HPM] GET /fake/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js -> http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js`

I also tried `context: ["fake/*"]` but that also 404ed and didn't trigger any proxy messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close. I needed a pathRewrite because the CLI preserves the folder `fake` when hitting target so the CLI was trying to get jquery from `https://code.jquery.com/fake/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js`.

I also wanted `secure: false` because that allows all certs instead of telling CLI what to expect, like I originally though.

And, since it isn't localhost we wanted to `changeOrigin: true`.

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [{
    context: ["/fake/"],
    target: "https://code.jquery.com/",
    pathRewrite: {
        "^/fake/": ""
    },
    secure: false,
    logLevel: "debug",
    changeOrigin: true
}];
```